# Error in induction proof

Tags: proof-verification, induction

What is wrong with the following proof?

Is it the fact that 5, 6 , 7 was never verified (base cases) because we never set a bound for k?

**Claim**: Any integral amount of postage greater than or equal to 5 cents can be made by using only 3-cent and 5-cent stamps.

**Proof**:
Base case: 5 cents postage can be made using one 5 cent stamp.
Inductive step: Assume that 5, 6, . . . , k cents postage can be made using only 3-cent and 5-cent stamps.
To make k + 1 cents postage, note that k + 1 = (k − 2) + 3. Since k − 2 ≤ k, the hypothesis of the inductive step implies that k − 2 cents postage can be made using only 3-cent and 5-cent stamps. By adding one more 3-cent stamp, we have a total of k + 1 cents postage using only 3-cent and 5-cent stamps.
Thus, by strong induction, any integral amount of postage greater than or equal to 5 cents can be made by using only 3-cent and 5-cent stamps.

Comment: How it is true for 7?

Comment: It is not, but the proof doesn't check. It only checks 5 and then proceeds with the induction. I'm a little confused, maybe the error is in the k-2..?

Comment: If you want to use strong induction and you also want the ability to subtract $3$, then you need to check three base cases, namely $5, 6, 7$, and of course you can't check $7$ because it's not true.

Comment: Because you are referring to element $k-2$, $k-2$ has to be satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To rewrite your inductive hypothesis:

> If $j\geq 5$ and $j \leq k$, then $j$ cents of postage can be made using only 3-cent and 5-cent stamps.

In the key step you attempt to use the inductive hypothesis for $k-2$.  You check that $k-2 \leq k$, but to use the hypothesis you would also need to know $k-2 \geq 5$... which is false when $k=6$.